# How or can I generalize an If-statement for multiple JButtons (color changing)?

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

So I'm trying to make multiple buttons do the same change in color when they are pressed. Each individual press should cycle through a predetermined cycle of colors (White, Red, Green, Yellow, Blue, Black). I could just make a long if-else-statement but for I'm pretty sure there's a better way, I just can't come up with one.

I have already tried "getSource().getBackground()" in the second if-statement but it's not able to get the same variable as the first if-statement does.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
    if(e.getSource() == btn1){  
      if(getSource().getBackground() == Color.white)  
        setBackground(Color.red);  
        else  
        setBackground(Color.white);  
    }
```

As previously stated I'm trying to minimize the effort here and make it also a bit more organized.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be something like:

1. Initialize a "button-pressed" counter. So have a variable outside your actionPerformed method and increment it everytime the button is pressed. Add some logic to reset the counter value once it  exceeds a certain threshold, i.e. after you cycled through your "last" colour, return to the first color.
2. Have a switch statement, which would set the background according to the value of the counter (essentially, how many times the button was pressed).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make a function that checks and changes background and then pass all my buttons to it.

```
public void checkAndChangeColor(Object source, Object btn, int bgToCheck, int bgToChange1, int bgToChange2){
    if (source == btn) {
        if (source.getBackground() == bgToCheck)
            setBackground(bgToChange1);
        else
            setBackground(bgToChange2);
    }
}
```

and then I would call that method on every button.

```
checkAndChangeColor(e.getSource(), btn, Color.white, Color.red, Color.white);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a private inner class that implements ActionListener and have a collection of colors inside it. Override actionPerformed and have an internal count so e.setBackground(colorList.get(count % colorList.size())

Comment: Sorry its poorly formatted on phone but here is how your actionlistener class would look 
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
Private int count,
Private ArrayList<Color> colors;
public ButtonListener(){
this.count = 0;
this.colors = ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE));
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
If(e.getSource instance of JButton){
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
( 
button.setBackground(colors.get(count));
button.repaint();
count = ++count % colors.size();
}
}